# My Connection Variable not resolve: how to make this connection work

Tags: java, eclipse, mysql-connector

```java
package com.silicon.core;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class jdbcConnection implements jdbc {
    public static Connection con;
    
    public static void Createconnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(jdbcConnection.urls);
            con =DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnection.url,jdbcConnection.username,jdbcConnection.password);
            System.out.println("Connection created..!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to connect package to another package both codes given below, jdbcConnection (Connection con) to  package jdbc insert.
in Eclipse. The error is as follows:

[Eclipse error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcLwP.jpg)

## Next Package

jdbc selectall();

Need to connect above program variable `con` to this below code connection con

```
package com.silicon.crud;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.silicon.core.jdbcConnection;

public class CRUDimpl implements Icrud {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jdbcConnection j= new jdbcConnection();
        CRUDimpl u=new CRUDimpl();
        u.insert();
        u.update();
        u.delete();
        sellectall();
    }
    
    public static void sellectall() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                int Eid = rs.getInt(1);
                String Ename = rs.getString(2);
                int Eage = rs.getInt(3);
                float Esalary =rs.getFloat(4);
                System.out.println(Eid +" "+Ename+" "+Eage+" "+Esalary);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Want this resolve:
MYSQL COnnection
in Eclipse.

Comment: that's not going to work. even if you import the variable correctly, it still won't be instantiated until you run the main method of that class

Comment: I need to use con from that package

Comment: first thing you should do, is realize that there is no point what-so-ever in having two 'public static void main(String[] args)' methods in a single application

Comment: as for using it, I 've already said why it doesn't work now, and what you'll have to do to make it work. It's best to first learn the basics before going to persistence tasks.

Comment: Ok sir I will change it

Comment: Sir Stultuske , sorry for that i need to check that connection so that only i created that main method to check the out put .After the changes still is the same error in that ,can you please tell the connection now.

Comment: what changes did you do?

Comment: i chage the main method and connected to package

Comment: and how did you do that? can you update the code above?

Comment: Note that since JDBC 4.0, there is autoloading of JDBC drivers. In earlier versions of JDBC, applications had to manually register drivers before requesting `Connection`s. With JDBC 4.0, applications no longer need to issue a `Class.forName()` on the driver name; instead, the `DriverManager` will find an appropriate JDBC driver when the application requests a `Connection`. Hence no need for this line of your code: `Class.forName(jdbcConnection.urls);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should be:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = jdbcConnection.con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
```

since `con` is a static member of class `jdbcConnection`.
Alternatively, you can use [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html), in which case you can use the line of code as it appears in your question, i.e.

```java
import static com.silicon.core.jdbcConnection.con;
.
.
.
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
```

However that still won't work because `con` is initialized in method `main`, of class `jdbcConnection`.

I suggest that you make class `jdbcConnection` a [singleton](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton) – as demonstrated in the below code.
Note that the code is just for demonstrating the singleton [design] pattern and that I use dummy values in the [static initializer](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-instance-initializer-block) of class `JdbcConnection` since I could not ascertain, from your question, what values to use. I'm sure you can supply those values.

By the way, I changed the name of class `jdbcConnection` so as to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Also, the below code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CRUDimpl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sellectall();
    }
    
    public static void sellectall() {
        try (Connection con = JdbcConnection.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee")) {
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                int Eid = rs.getInt(1);
                String Ename = rs.getString(2);
                int Eage = rs.getInt(3);
                float Esalary =rs.getFloat(4);
                System.out.println(Eid +" "+Ename+" "+Eage+" "+Esalary);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class JdbcConnection {
    private static final Connection con;

    static {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "password");
        }
        catch (SQLException xSql) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(xSql);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```